# How to pass data from sources to template function?

Tags: php, smf

If I make a `SELECT` query from the sources file (sources/Example.php), then how would I pass the returned data to the template function being called?

**sources/Example.php**

```
function DoSomething()
{
    global $context;
    loadTemplate('Example');
    $data = <get some data by querying the database>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    $context['sub_template'] = 'listData';

    // now pass this $data to the listData function
}
```

**themes/default/Example.template.php**

```
function template_listData()
{
    // access $data here
}
```

One thing that I can think of is creating a key in the `$context` array and assigning the data to that key. But I was wondering if there is a better/alternate approach to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949864/3859027 i've used this as some kind of reference in the past

Comment: or you can just use a complete mvc framework if it suits your needs like codeigniter or laravel

Comment: @Kevin Not entirely sure if I can follow that approach given that Simple Machine Forums does not use OOP

Comment: i think you'd still be able to apply the linked answer above as it just requires inclusion of few files around. or you could use persistent storage like sessions